# Remove 'typo3-neu' from url

Tags: typo3-8.x

I want to remove `typo3-neu` from my url.
http://p440057.webspaceconfig.de/typo3-neu/kurse-seminare/

Any help will be good.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably use ext:realurl you need a proper configuration.
As you give no more information (¹) I can only guess.

You might need to configure the correct root page.

You can exclude the URL segment of a page for all pages below.

You can configure the full path for each page individually.

(¹) please provide information about your pagetree and your realurl configuration (realurl_conf.php)

Comment: sorry for not answering until now... it was some configuration settings from the server provider